# What does で means in this sentence?

Tags: particle-で

- 中国人で日本語が話せる方

I think it's traduction would be:

- Chinese people who can speak Japanese

But I have searched for references of this で usage yet I haven't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a particle, this で is the [te-form](https://www.imabi.net/theparticlete.htm) of だ.

So the meaning of the relative clause attached to 方 is: “is a Chinese person **and** can speak Japanese”.

You can compare it to the で you put after na-adjectives (example also from imabi):

> 6. 東京は賑やか**で**面白い。
>    Tōkyō wa nigiyaka de omoshiroi.
>    Tokyo is lively and interesting.

Nouns and na-adjectives are not so different, after all.